# Contact form 7 (wordpress)

Tags: forms, wordpress, contacts

I´m using contact form 7 on my website to get customers to order
products from my Wordpress site.

But I want to let the user (customers) to add their own form fields if they want to add other products then listed in the form.

Is that possible?

Comment: add a different field for product items instead of the products listed . . else add a separate field for additional product items none other than in the list . . Contact form 7 doesn't let you work on it's database dynamically . .

Answer (score 0):

Fields in the CF7 creator are inserted as a kind of shortcode/internal format, and after that it passes a parser that changes them into valid HTML form elements. What you can do, is to use  DOM (Document Object Model) to create a new element - but then, you should definitely pay attention to your PHP code afterwards.